# Как сделать короткую директорию в QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

Суть вот в чем. Пытаюсь сделать обозреватель директорий относительно конечного приложения. То есть отображения дерева только на уровне и выше расположения приложения. Ну и ограничить до кучи отображение только определенными файлами. Голову уже поломал.

Вот что я наверетел по коду:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
    model->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
    model->setFilter(QDir::Files);
    model->setNameFilters(QStringList () << "*.txt");

    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->treeView->setModel(model);    //Объект  в UI-редакторе QTreeView

    db.close();
}
```

Помогите кто может, ибо я ужо подзадолбался.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на собственный вопрос) Достаточно после задания модели установить "корневой индекс древовидного представления":

```
ui->treeView->setRootIndex(model->index(QDir::currentPath()));
```

Прямым текстом, вот прям символ в символ в мануале написано, блин...

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setFilter